# How to use IntegralToString

Tags: android

I am working on a android App and am trying to use IntegralToString, android studio always prompt "Cannot resolve symbol IntegralToString".

I find source [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.4_r1/tools/layoutlib/create/src/com/android/tools/layoutlib/java/IntegralToString.java)

but I cannot import com.android.tools.layoutlib.java package in my Java code, can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: I think you deleted the link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am working on a android App and am trying to use IntegralToString, android studio always prompt "Cannot resolve symbol IntegralToString".

That is because there is no class in the Android SDK named `IntegralToString`, at least at this time.

> I find source here

That is source code for some of the development tools.

> can anyone help?

Copy the Java code into your own project, adhering to the license terms.

Comment: these is comment like this "Defines the same class as the java.lang.IntegralToString", is it in Java stand lib? it is odd, why does it show up in the android source code lib, Thx?

Comment: @JohnDing: Most of the Java code in Android is not part of the Android SDK.